# How to extract specific substring from getline function in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, compare, extract

I'm fairly new to C++ so please forgive me if my terminology or methodology isn't correct.

I'm trying to write a simple program that:

1. Opens two input files ("infileicd" and "infilesel").
2. Opens a single output file "list.txt".
3. Compares "infilesel" to "infileicd" line by line.
4. If a line from "infilesel" is found in "infileicd", it writes that line from "infileicd" to "list.txt", effectively making a separate log file.

I am using the getline() function to do this but have run into trouble when trying to compare each file line. I think it might be easier if I could use only the substring of interest to use as a comparison.
The problem is that there are multiple words within the entire getline string and I am only really interested in the second one. Here are two examples:

"1529   nic1_mau_op_mode_3                  "8664afm007-01" "1" OUTPUT  1 0 LOGICAL 4   4136"

"1523   pilot_mfd_only_sel                  "8664afm003-02" "1" OUTPUT  1 0 LOGICAL 4   4112"

"nic1_mau_op_mode_3" and "pilot_mfd_only_sel" are the only substrings of interest.

It would make it a lot easier if I could only use that second substring to compare but I don't know how to extract it specifically from the getline() function. I haven't found anything suggesting it is impossible to do this, but if it is impossible, what would be an alternative method for extracting that substring?

This is a personal project so I'm under no time contstraints.

Any assistance is greatly apprecated in advance. Here is my code (so far):

```
int main()
{
    //Open the file to write the selected variables to.
    ofstream writer("list.txt");

    //Open the selected variabels file to be read.
    ifstream infilesel;
    infilesel.open("varsel.txt");

    //Open the icd file to be read.
    ifstream infileicd;
    infileicd.open("aic_fdk_host.txt");

    //Check icd file for errors.
    if (infileicd.fail()){
        cerr << "Error opening icd.\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The icd file has been opened.\n";
    }

    //Check selected variables file for errors.
    if (infilesel.fail()){
        cerr << "Error opening selection file.\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The selection file has been opened.\n";
    }

    //Read each infile and copy contents of icd file to the list file.

    string namesel;
    string nameicd;

    while(!infileicd.eof()){ 

        getline(infileicd, nameicd);
        getline(infilesel, namesel);

        if (nameicd != namesel){ //This is where I would like to extract and compare the two specific strings
            infileicd; //Skip to next line if not the same

        } else {
                writer << nameicd << namesel << endl;
        } 
    }


    writer.close();
    infilesel.close();
    infileicd.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you only comparing part of the line because the other sections may differ, but if they do you don't care?

Comment: @David: Correct. I only really care about that second substring. The reason is because the format for both input files is identical.

Comment: Can you post a few real lines, and the data you want from those?

Comment: @David: Added to post.

Comment: Put in the main post please. Hard to distingist lines in comments. Also, please say which text you want to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on what we discussed in the comments, you just need to toss the stuff you don't want. So try this:

```
string namesel;
string nameicd;
string junk;

while(!infileicd.eof()){ 

    // Get the first section, which we'll ignore
    getline(infileicd, junk, ' ');
    getline(infilesel, junk, ' ');

    // Get the real data
    getline(infileicd, nameicd, ' ');
    getline(infilesel, namesel, ' ');

    // Get the rest of the line, which we'll ignore
    getline(infileicd, junk);
    getline(infilesel, junk);
```

Basically, `getline` takes a delimiter, which by default is a newline. By setting it as a space the first time, you get rid of the first junk section, using the same method, you get the part you want, and then the final portion goes to the end of the line, also ignoring it.

Comment: The compiler is telling me that it's only expecting 2 arguments for getline, not 3.

Comment: Sorry, see edit. Should have been single quotes (') not double (").

Comment: OH ok, it compiles and runs now. So, nameicd and namesel are now only containing the substring I want right? Junk throws away the rest?

Comment: Yep. do a `cout` to confirm if you'd like.

Comment: Uh oh, when I cout, it's giving me the "8664afm003-004" string instead.

Comment: What does junk give you after the first time?

Comment: It gives me the number first, then the string I need, separated by a space.

Comment: So it's giving you "1529 nic1..."? Your file does have a valid space (ASCII 32) as that character, right?

Comment: Correct, and I'm not certain but I would assume so. I wouldn't be able to explain the white space otherwise.

Comment: It's dropping everything after the substring correctly. So I don't know why it wouldn't be dropping the substring after that first space.

Comment: Whitespace isn't always a space. Could be a ASCII 255, or some other unicode character. Read the characters in one by one and output their integer values (by casting them to an int) to see what you get.

Comment: Well, David thank you for your help. To the extent of the question, I believe your answer is sufficient. The rest is up to me to work out. Thank you again. :)